# Paste picture into picturebox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm extremely new to Excel VBA and coding in general. I've tried to make the following code, but it only work down to the 'copy the chart as an image. The part of actually 'paste' the image, does not work properly and I get the following error message:

"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set"

What is the problem here exactly?
I'm trying to get the copied image inserted to the picturebox inside my userform.

Image of code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, please refer to how to ask a good question, and also add your code as text, not an image. This way we can copy the code for quick testing. I doubt anyone would want to type your code out manually.